# Debugging has not been enabled on server

Tags: wcf, web-services

I am new to WCF architecture.

When I am debugging an application, it gives me the error:

"Unable to step into a server. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on server."

The execution scenario is like:

Line by line execution from top to bottom. When debug execution flow comes to the line that generates error, it calls a web service (having one line above service signature that is

"http://liveUrl", RequestNamespace:="http://liveUrl/", ResponseNamespace:="http://liveUrl/", Use:=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle:=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)>  _ ")

So, can you help me determine what is the issue, or Is there any way to debug this.

Comment: Is the service on a different machine?  You can't (very easily) debug code that is on a different machine.  If you have the project for that service, you can put a copy on your local machine, at which point there are a couple of ways to debug (either attach the debugger to the service or have the project in your solution).

Comment: my project & web service both are hosted on same server and I've rights of RDP on server(My own, even I can copy code there).